# Oracle: searching over a range of values?

Tags: oracle11g

```
CREATE TABLE  "DEPARTMENT" 
   (    "DEP_NO" NUMBER(*,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "SSN" NUMBER(*,0), 
    "STREET" CHAR(40) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "CITY" CHAR(25) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "NAME" CHAR(50) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "BUDGET" NUMBER(8,2), 
     CONSTRAINT "PK_DEPARTMENT" PRIMARY KEY ("DEP_NO") ENABLE
   ) ;

ALTER TABLE  "DEPARTMENT" ADD CONSTRAINT "FK_DEPARTMENT_EMPLOYEE" FOREIGN KEY ("SSN")
      REFERENCES  "EMPLOYEE" ("SSN") ENABLE;
ALTER TABLE  "DEPARTMENT" ADD CONSTRAINT "FK_DEPARTMENT_LOCATION" FOREIGN KEY ("STREET", "CITY")
      REFERENCES  "LOCATION" ("STREET", "CITY") ENABLE;
```

what is the correct way in building a data base , is it better to create the tables with their primary keys , insert the data and then link these tables to another tables with the foreign key or it is better to create all the tables , link them together and then insert the required data ???

Answer (score 0):

There is no correct way. Both approaches can be used.

The simpler approach is to first create all the tables, indexes and constraints and then to insert the data.

For maximum performance, first create just the tables and the primary key indexes, then insert the data and finally create the additional indexes and the constraints.